# Combinatorial problem on set

Tags: combinatorics

For a subset $X = \left\{x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right\}$ of the set of positive integers, $X + X$ denotes the set
$\left\{x_{i} + x_{j} \mid i \neq j\right\}$ and
$\left\vert X\right\vert$ denotes the number of elements in $X$.

$\mathbf{A}$). Do there exist subsets $A, B$ of positive integers such that $\left\vert A\right\vert = \left\vert A\right\vert |B|  = 3,\ A \not= B\ \mbox{and}\ A + A =B + B$?.

$\mathbf{B}$). Show that if $n = 2^{k}$, then there exist subsets
$A, B$ of positive integers such that $\left\vert A\right\vert = \left\vert B\right\vert = n,\ A \not= B\ \mbox{and}\  A + A =B + B$. Prove it with induction.

I am not being able to do it please help.

Comment: Please, see [$\texttt{MathJax}$ Basic Tutorial and Quick Reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(A) The answer is no, as the three elements of $A$ are determined by the three sums in $A+A$. For example, if $A+A=\{8,11,13\}$, then it must be the case that $A=\{3,5,8\}$. I will let you think a little more about how to recover $A$ from $A+A$.

(B) Let $A_k,B_k$ be unequal sets of $2^k$ positive integers for which $A_k+A_k=B_k+B_k$. Let $N_k$ be the largest number appearing in $A_k$ or $B_k$. Given a set of numbers $C$, let $C+N=\{c+N:c\in C\}$. Then let
\begin{align}
A_{k+1} &= A_k\cup (B_k +N) \\
B_{k+1} &= B_k\cup (A_k + N)
\end{align}
You can show that $A_{k+1}\neq B_{k+1}$, and that $A_{k+1}+A_{k+1}=B_{k+1}+B_{k+1}$.

Provided you have the base cases $A_1,B_1$, then the above construction lets you prove $A_k,B_k$ exist for all $k\ge 1$ by induction. Any singleton sets $A_1\neq B_1$ will do, as $A_1+A_1$ and $B_1+B_1$ will both be empty sets.

With the base cases $A_1=\{1\}$ and $B_1=\{2\}$, we get
\begin{array}{ll}
A_2=\{1,4\} & B_2=\{2,3\}\\
A_3=\{1,4,6,7\} & B_3=\{2,3,5,8\}\\
A_4=\{1,4,6,7,10,11,13,16\} & B_4 = \{2,3,5,8,9,12,14,15\}
\end{array}