# Two sequences with the same pairwise sums

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, examples-counterexamples, generating-functions

Find all integers $n \geq 2$ for which there exist distinct sequences of integers $a_1, a_2, \dots a_n$ and $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n$ such that the set of sums $a_i + a_j$, $1\leq i < j \leq n$, is a permutation of the set of sums $b_i + b_j$, $1\leq i < j \leq n$.

It is a classical exercise in generating functions to show that $n$ must necessarily be equal to a power of two. However, is it true that for any power of two there is a possible example? (For $n=2$ there clearly are such and I tried some inductive construction, but nothing worked.) Or perhaps the generating functions approach can be extended to show that only $n=2$ is possible?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3068072) answer your question? Also, I would be very curious to learn what the generating function proof is.

Comment: Wow, amazing, thank you a lot! For the generating function proof see Problem 7 here https://imomath.com/index.cgi?page=generatingFunctionsProblems